# Change the Result Text in Ant

Tags: logging, ant

Ant finishes by printing:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: x minute y seconds
```

Is there an easy way to customize that text?  Sometimes I'm not using Ant to build, but for other batch processes, and I'd like to avoid seeing BUILD SUCCESSFUL when no build was attempted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message is issued by the default `BuildLogger` ant uses.
See [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/listeners.html) for the list of builtin loggers ant provides.

If you want something special, you can simply run ant with:

```
ant -logger org.apache.tools.ant.NoBannerLogger
```

for example, or use your own implementation of the [`BuildLogger`](http://api.dpml.net/ant/1.6.5/org/apache/tools/ant/BuildLogger.html) interface. The easiest way is to derive from `DefaultLogger`, overriding whant you want to change. You can for example implement your own

```
public void buildFinished(BuildEvent event)
```

method, if you want customized ending messages.